# UITableViewCell content incorrect when editing and scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My tableview works perfectly fine when not in editing mode. All cells show up as expected, but if I enter editing mode and scroll, the cells that are redrawn while in editing mode have the incorrect content. In my function that turns off editing, I reload the table data and it shows up correctly again.

Here the relevant code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


FieldItemDecrypted *theField = [decryptedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




    // Configure the cell...

      cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theField.field encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theField.type encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    


return cell;
}
```

And my code for editing:

```
- (IBAction)editRows:(id)sender
{

if ([self.tableView isEditing])
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
else
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

}
```

Should look like this:

[image]

but looks like this after scrolling while editing:

[image]

Comment: Also I tried adding this code in the cell for row at indexpath method:
     NSLog(@"position = %@ field = %@",theField.position,theField.field); 
In the debugger it shows up correctly as if it's queueing up the correct cell, but it doesn't display correctly.

Comment: when exactly does that bug happen? So if you start editing it it's fine, but if you scroll while editing you get that `1` in the numbers?

Comment: Exactly, but I don't think it's adding a one, I think it's recycling the cells from the bottom of the table so that's 15, 14, 13 12, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing a `UITableViewCell` object first, then dequeuing from the table view? This is incorrect.

Try:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

I just tried this on a demo project and it behaves as expected.

Comment: Tried that, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Steven please see edit. You were not initializing your cells with the identifier. I just tried on a demo project and everything works as expected.

Comment: Ok, found the error. I actually had another if statement in the cellforrowatindex that checked if it was in editing mode, the label was being assigned inside the if statement instead of outside of it. Not sure how I missed that, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with this type of cell reuse:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (!cell) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
  }
  FieldItemDecrypted *theField = [decryptedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  // Configure the cell...

  cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theField.field encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theField.type encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    


  return cell;
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you change other than what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I gave him a copy of how his method would look in our system.  And it is a method that works appropriately in my system, so I know that if it doesn't work for him, he must have a problem elsewhere that is causing it.

Comment: But your copy is a copy paste from his question with my suggestion for fix. What else have your changed?

Comment: Your suggestion?  I'm sorry, I barely glanced at it.  I copied my standard cellForRowAtIndexPath method from my project and filled in his configuration.

Comment: This code works, I built a test program and it worked fine, so my problem is elsewhere.